# How to prevent a view layer from rendering?

Tags: rendering

How to prevent a view layer from rendering?

I'm rendering bunch of objects and some needs to be rendered in 2 passes, but most of them don't and I'd like only render the first view layer for those. How do I keep my extra view layer but prevent Cycles from rendering it?

Comment: Under *View Layer Properties*, enable *Render Single Layer*.